# cv.filter2D return TypeError

Tags: python, opencv

My platform is Mac OS X 10.6 and install python 2.7.2/opencv by homebrew.
I want to use cv.filter2D to do Lanczos resampling, here is my code:

```
import cv

src = cv.imread('img.jpg')
dst = cv.CloneMat(src)
kernel = cv.CreateMat(7, 7, cv.CV_32FC1)

for i in range(-3, 4):
    for j in range(-3, 4):
        kernel[i+3, j+3] = L(i, 3) * L(j, 3)

cv.filter2D(src, dst, kernel)
cv.imshow(dst)
```

My problem is cv.filter2D. 
If I use

```
cv.filter2D(src, dst, kernel)
```

, which wrote in OpenCV Reference Manual, it will get error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lanczos.py", line 27, in <module>
    cv.filter2D(src, dst, kernel)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Under python I type

```
cv.filter2D.__doc__
```

, it said the function prototype is

```
'filter2D(src, ddepth, kernel[, dst[, anchor[, delta[, borderType]]]]) -> dst'
```

if I use

```
cv.filter2D(src, -1, kernel, dst)
```

instead, the error message become

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lanczos.py", line 27, in <module>
    cv.filter2D(src, 1 , kernel, dst)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

seems no people encounter this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is the version of your opencv, my version is:

```
>>> import cv2 as cv
>>> cv.__version__
'$Rev: 4557 $'
```

I can use a ndarray as the kernel, and don't need to create an empty array for the result, filter2D() will return a new ndarray.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
src = cv.imread('img.jpg')
kernel = np.ones((7,7), dtype=np.float)/49.0
dst = cv.filter2D(src, -1, kernel)
cv.imwrite("result.jpg", dst)
```

Comment: I don't have module named cv2, but my cv.__version__ is '$Rev: 3057 $'

I can run your code correctly, seems the problem is kernel format